# How to handle RabbitMQ with mobile apps

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-endpoints, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking to implement rabbitmq on google compute engine to handle messages on my android and ios messaging app. I have heard that rabbitmq can be quite power hungry, so i am wondering what the best solution to combat this is?
Do i use a different protocol like MQTT or so i use something like GCM to handle the connection to and from the apps and let rabbitmq just handle queuing the messages?

Comment: what exactly do you mean "power hungry"? As in it consumes far too much CPU-cycles?

Comment: I meant battery, i heard that it drains battery down on mobile devices because it keeps connections open for too long

Answer (score 5):

You would never want make a direct connection from mobile device to your RabbitMQ server, especially if the app on the device is a consumer. RabbitMQ consumers have to poll RabbitMQ continuously to check if there are messages pending for them. You would want a web-server to handle actual HTTP POST/GET of messages from devices. The webserver will do two things:

1. Save the message to DB (along with the source and intended destination info)
2. queue APN/GCM push messages to a RabbitMQ (the broker here) exchange

   you will need to build a daemon to monitor RabbitMQ for these push messages that have been queued. The daemon's sole task would be to connect or maintain a connection to Apple's or Google's push messaging services and notify your apps that they have a message pending. If a device is notified of a pending message, it contacts the webserver to consume the message

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so basically i use rabbitmq to handle the messages backend and use something like gcm ccs to communicate from the device to rabbitmq?

Comment: RabbitMQ is a message broker. Use it as a broker between the webserver and the APN/GCM daemon to notify a user's device that there is a message waiting for it. I's a little complicated because you have to figure out what to do if a device is offline and it does not get the APN/GCM notification (ie. you have to have a retry policy and when not to retry which is necessary if the user's device reads the message before the push message has been delivered)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you think it is better to not use rabbitmq and just use gcm xmpp to handle the messaging?

Comment: XMPP is way of an overkill, to be used where "presence" of a user is required.